# Laravel Passport Connection Refused when posting credentials using Guzzle/Http Facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, bearer-token

I have just finished to configure Laravel-passport in my API, but I am having issue issuing tokens.

- Laravel V10
- Passport V11
- API served using: `php artisan server --port=5000`

When I try to login using postman:

With **PHP8.1**, after a while I get the error below:

> cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

With **PHP8.2**

> Connection refused for URI http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token

Here is where I make the call:

```
/** @var User $user */
$user = $this->userModel->query()->where('email', $data['email'])->first() ?? throw
new ModelNotFoundException('Your
 credentials do not match our record');

$payload = [
    'grant_type'    => 'password',
    'client_id'     => config('passport.personal_grant_client.id'),
    'client_secret' => config('passport.personal_grant_client.secret'),
    'username'      => $data['email'],
    'password'      => $data['password'],
    'scope'         => '*',
];
$response = Http::asForm()->post(route('passport.token'), $payload); // This fails and return the error above
```

But when I directly POST to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token`
with all the required params in the snippet above, the token is issued without any issue.

I would like to note that, I have a similar setup for another project with Passport v7 and it works without issue, but with most recent version of Passport I am getting the same problem.

For instance, I have another project, which just hang when trying to logging locally but work on the live server.

**Edit:**

Event though the token is return and the above error is thrown, record for `oauth_access_tokens` and `oauth_refresh_tokens` are being created in the database.

**Edit**: issue sovled

I  decide to start using `Laravel-valet` again, I am just surprised that, it is working with one API and the rest not.